# Drag and drop disables input textfield! Help me?

Tags: javascript, html, input, drag

i have a input textfield within a container.
This container is draggable, but now i cant input text into the textfield anymore.
Probably because you have to click inside the textfield to type,
and now mouse down means drag!

Or maybe its something completly different

Does anyone know how i can solve this? 
Thanks in advance

you can check the code out here, but its pretty much..
http://www.jsfiddle.net/AVG5a/

Comment: you should show some code. That can help even those who have never faced this, to help you. Otherwise you loose many helpers

Comment: I agree sounds like a interesting question but difficult to answer without code!

Comment: thanks for your comment, i just thought it would be too much and i would probably scare everyone off but okay thanks for your feedback

Comment: ok but where is the textfield to type?

Comment: var input = create("input");
    input.type = "input";
    input.id = "inputId" + counter;
    div.appendChild(input);

Comment: okay it appears on clicking append. got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) <sup>[*[docs]*](http://api.jquery.com)</sup> and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) <sup>[*[docs]*](http://jqueryui.com/demos)</sup>. <s>I'm almost done with converting to jQuery, I'll post a jsFiddle link when I finish it.</s>

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pswRh/

After you learn jQuery and jQuery UI, it's very easy to make an element draggable, and – optionally – disable dragging it with a specified child element.

**HTML**

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    <img src='http://dummyimage.com/100x100.png' id='pic' />
    <input id='textInput' />
</div>
```

**CSS** (optional)

```
#myDiv {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myDiv').draggable({
    cancel: '#textInput'
});
```

And voila! You've just made a draggable div, but you can still type in the input field, since it won't drag the element.

Alternatively, you can specify a handle. That way, you can only drag the div with the specified child.

**HTML, CSS**

*same as previous*

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myDiv').draggable({
  handle: '#pic'
});
```

Specify multiple elements separated by a comma (i.e. `'#el1, #el2, #el3'`).

Comment: thank you so much!!!! very helpful and starting to learn jquery right away! Thanks Nyuszika7H!!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I've removed the counters, as they're too complicated, and unneccessary in most cases. If you need a thing like this, use [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector ":eq() Selector – jQuery API") or [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq ".eq() – jQuery API") instead.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to `appendFunction`:

```
document.getElementById("inputId0").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

This will cancel `mousedown` events for the element with id `inputId0`.

Comment: i have a counter with the id's should it be like this;
document.getElementById("inputId" + counter).addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) { e.stopPropagation();}, false;

Comment: well with the code above the buttons doesnt work anymore, strange